# Ruby: can't change values in two-dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Decided to make a method for creating two-dimensional array. The array looks well, but when I'm trying to change the value, I change that value in all the sub-arrays, so it looks like this:

```
a[0][0] = 0
```

[[0, "*", "*"], [0, "*", "*"], [0, "*", "*"]]

Any ideas how to make it work properly?

Here's the method for creating the array:

```
def create_array(size)
array = []
line = []
size.times { line << "*" }
size.times { array << line }
array
end
```

Comment: Your `create_array` puts the same `line` in each row of your 2D array. And what's `size`? Is it a square matrix, with `size` rows and `size` columns?

Comment: @lurker Yes, that's what I need. But when I modify the array, I change values in all lines, but I want to change the value only in one line. Yes, that's that square matrix

Comment: Like I said, each line is the *same* line. It's the same array object in each row of `array`. So when you change one, you've changed them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code puts the same `line` in each row of `array`:

```
def create_array(size)
  array = []                # Create an Array object, "array"
  line = []                 # Create an Array object, "line"

  size.times { line << "*" }

  # The following line puts the SAME Array object, "line", into
  # array "size" times
  #
  size.times { array << line }
  array
end
```

You need to put a new one in each time. I assume by `size` you mean that's a square matrix:

```
def create_array(size)
  Array.new(size) { Array.new(size, "*") }
end
```

Here, `Array.new(n, elt)` creates a new Array object of length `n` and filled with element, `elt`. See [Ruby Array "new" method](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new). Note that trying to do something like this has a similar issue as the original problem:

```
Array.new(size, Array.new(size, "*"))
```

In this case, `Array.new(size, "*")` occurs *once* and as passed as the second argument to the "outer" `Array.new(size, ...)`, so each row here is also the same Array object. Passing the block to `Array.new(...)` as above generates a separate `Array.new(size, "*")` call for each row.

Comment: Thank tou so much! Now I understand that I need to create new array each time rather than using the same object